# html css how to make page width fixed so that when resizing screen it will pan right and left instead?

Tags: html, css

I need to show a html page where the layout doesn't move or change when resizing the screen, but actually pan, so even on mobile the layout is still the same albeit having to scroll left and right.

I have tried wrapping my whole html and set it this way, but still doesn't work.

```
#wrapper {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:960px;
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Can you share more code in snippets

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting it to work by changing `width:960px` into `min-width:960px`, the rest is the same.